# How to change PowerBI data source parameter in ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I made a Power BI report that connects to a SQL database and let's me change databases by updating a parameter. This works well when I publish the report and change the parameter in Power BI online.

Now, I want to add this report to an ASP.NET MVC application. I need to know how to change the database parameter from within the .NET app, like I can in Power BI online. Is it possible to do this?

FYI: the scenario is, we have multi tenant application and each tenant has it's own database. Now, we want to load the report for the logged in tenant.

For example, if the Tenant1 is logged in, then our ASP.NET MVC application should pass the tenant database name as parameter value and it should load the report for that tenant, if Tenant2 logged in then it should load the report for that tenant only and so on.

Thanks.

I tried following things

- I have created power bi report which has dynamic Tenant Parameter with list values
- Assign that parameter to the connection of database.
- Custom Functions in power bi and pass that function name and value to the embed url
- Filter concept in front
- Bookmarks > Using this it requires multiple dataset at a time.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you will need Power BI Embedded to be set up in your Azure subscription so you can embed your Power BI reports your .NET MVC app.

Register your application in Azure AD for your .NET MVC app for the step of authenticating and obtaining access tokens to interact with Power BI content.

Regarding the db parameter, I think that direct dynamic parameter modification at runtime isn't natively supported by Power BI Embedded, but you can achieve that by using dynamic filtering on your report dataset directly through the Power BI JavaScript API.

So instead of changing the connection string, you filter the report data based on the tenant identifier.

And then you have to implement RLS in your Power BI report to control data access based on the tenant.

Each tenant data is separated at the database level, and RLS will ensure tenants can only access their own data.

Your .NET MVC app will need to authenticate the user, determine their tenant, and pass the appropriate RLS role when embedding the report.

Check the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-organization-app